# How to merge a series of two fields into a series of one field in Acrobat with javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I have this data in an **Excel** file:

```
First Name_1    Amy
First Name_2    Bobby
First Name_3    Courteney
First Name_4    
First Name_5    
Last Name_1     Adams
Last Name_2     Brown
Last Name_3     Cox
Last Name_4 
Last Name_5
```

I arranged the data horizontally ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LHgu.png)) and saved it as a **.txt** file.

I need to get these names into a **pdf**, so I created [a form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz02y.png) in **Adobe Acrobat** with 15 fields named like this:

```
First Name_1
Last Name_1
Full Name_1

First Name_2
Last Name_2
Full Name_2

First Name_3
Last Name_3
Full Name_3

First Name_4
Last Name_4
Full Name_4

First Name_5
Last Name_5
Full Name_5
```

**I need to to merge the first and last name of each person into their respective full name field.**

This is how I did it: I right-clicked on the page's thumbnail and selected 
[Page Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP2sF.png) and clicked on Actions tab. Then I created a [javascript that would run on Page Open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQSSO.png) and I entered this code:

```
var firstName1 = this.getField("First Name_1").valueAsString;
var lastName1 = this.getField("Last Name_1").valueAsString;
this.getField("Full Name_1").value = lastName1 + ", " + firstName1;

var firstName2 = this.getField("First Name_2").valueAsString;
var lastName2 = this.getField("Last Name_2").valueAsString;
this.getField("Full Name_2").value = lastName2 + ", " + firstName2;

var firstName3 = this.getField("First Name_3").valueAsString;
var lastName3 = this.getField("Last Name_3").valueAsString;
this.getField("Full Name_3").value = lastName3 + ", " + firstName3;

var firstName4 = this.getField("First Name_4").valueAsString;
var lastName4 = this.getField("Last Name_4").valueAsString;
this.getField("Full Name_4").value = lastName4 + ", " + firstName4;

var firstName5 = this.getField("First Name_5").valueAsString;
var lastName5 = this.getField("Last Name_5").valueAsString;
this.getField("Full Name_5").value = lastName5 + ", " + firstName5;
```

When I import the **.txt** file I get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QtI3.png).

My main question is: **how can I write a shorter code?** I need to populate the form with dozens of names, and I believe I don't have to write three lines of code for each name.

Another question is: how can I get rid of the **lonely commmas** that show up when there is no data for those fields?

*Cheers!*

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way!

*[EDIT: check my other solution as well. I believe it is a better one]*

```
for ( var i = 1; i < 26; i++)
{
    this.getField ("Full Name_" + i).value = this.getField("Last Name_" + i).valueAsString
    + ", "
    + this.getField("First Name_" + i).valueAsString;
}
```

I just tweaked [BarlaeDC](https://forums.adobe.com/people/BarlaeDC#)'s answer to "[javascript for sequential fields within a pdf](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2502698)". The force is strong with this dude ;)

If somebody can improve my code, go ahead, please. I'd greatly appreciate it.

For instance: **does anybody know how to get rid of those intrusive commas?**. I need them to show up only in fields with data.

*Cheers!*

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a better solution**.

This one prevents commas from showing up in empty fields:

```
for ( var i = 1; i < 26; i++) //Up to 25 series will be affected
{
//If the Full Name field is not empty...
if (this.getField("Full Name_" + i).value.length!=0) {
//...leave it as it is.
    this.getField("Full Name_" + i).value = this.getField("Full Name_" + i).valueAsString
//If the First Name field is empty...
} else if (this.getField("First Name_" + i).value.length==0) {
//...duplicate the "Last Name" field on the "Full Name" one.
    this.getField("Full Name_" + i).value = this.getField("Last Name_" + i).valueAsString
//Else...
} else {
//...merge "Last Name, First Name" into the "Full Name" field.
    this.getField("Full Name_" + i).value = this.getField("Last Name_" + i).valueAsString
    + ", "
    + this.getField("First Name_" + i).valueAsString;
}
}
```